# Extending IdentityUser not loading added fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm using Asp.Net and Microsoft Identity. I am extending IdentityUser in order to add some extra information.

My IdentityUser override:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace DASBlazorSite.Data
{
    public class SiteUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public SiteUser() : base()
        {
        }

        public AspNetUserDetail UserData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AspNetUserDetail:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DASBlazorSite.Data
{
    public class AspNetUserDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

After doing the add-migration update-database thing, I see the AspNetUserDetail table being created. I also see an extra column in AspNetUsers, `UserDataId`.
When I modify a user, and save it with `UserManager.UpdateAsync(SiteUser)` I see the GUID populate in AspNetUsers, and the matching GUID in AspNetUserDetail. I also see the corresponding values for `FirstName`, etc. populated in AspNetUserDetail as well.
All looks good at this point. However, when I retrieve the user through `UserManager` the `UserData` field is null.
Is this some sort of Entity Framework lazy/eager loading thing? Any suggestions on how I would set out to correct it?
Oddly enough, if I load a user, then set the null `UserData` to a `new AspNetUserDetail` and fill in the corresponding values, then perform a `UserManager.UpdateAsync(SiteUser)` an entirely new entry is created in the AspNetUserDetail table. It has a new GUID, and the `UserDataId` field now points to it. The previous entry in AspNetUserDetail now sits there orphaned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related entities are never loaded automatically. You have to either eagerly load them using `Include` or rely on lazy loading (which is not enabled by default, and inadvisable to use in general). The problem here is that `UserManager` provides no facility to issue joins via `Include`. You can go ahead and enable lazy-loading, but that will actually cause a new query to issued when the property is accessed. This can lead to the N+1 query problem, when doing things like iterating, and can quickly spiral out of control to absolutely hammer your database. This is why lazy-loading is not advisable: it's too hard to ensure that you're efficiently querying the database and not obvious that you're not.

The best thing to do if you're in a situation where you *need* to load a related entity on the user is to just use the context directly, instead of `UserManager`:

```
var user = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.AspNetUserDetail).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId);
```

With all that said, you're creating a problem where none exists. The whole entire point of having an extensible user entity is to be able to add extra data *directly on that entity*. You should not be using a "profile" class like this, in the first place. Put the first name, last name, etc. properties directly on the `SiteUser` entity, and then there's nothing you need to join.

Comment: I see your point about a "profile" class. This is just a scratch demo. In the end, I will probably end up adding 30-40 columns of user data. I had hoped to keep things segregated just for the times when I would have to go in and browse the database, but with a one-to-one relationship, may be better to do it the way you suggest.

Comment: You should also evaluate what should actually on the entity and what should merely be a claim. Claims are best for transient data (e.g. a Facebook auth token) or stuff not applicable to every user.